# A free way to convert camel case to snake case and snake case to camel case

Tags: conversion, text-editors, text-editing

I have a bunch of **camelCase** sentences / words. I need to convert them into **snake_case** sentences / words. What is the best way to do so?

I would prefer free solution. Maybe notepad++ can do it?

Maybe there is a free web resource to convert **camelCase** to **snake_case**?
That would be better, it would be platform independent.

Comment: What?  This is simple.  Try making it a [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) question.  Or, specify a desired language/platform.  (Oh, I see you answered this yourself.)

Comment: I wanted to save time on coding and just do the conversion.

Comment: This question is closed so I cannot put this in an answer but if you are a vim user check out https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since I did not find any converters online, I made my own. Please try it on JSFIDDLE.

https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene82/e1dguw5f/2/

Comment: For future internet travellers, I forked it to be multiline: https://jsfiddle.net/a80mwedr/4/